# How to prevent the disappearance of the search bar in mui-datatables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, mui-datatable

I'm working on a project with mui-datables.
For sure I can catch the `onSearchClose` event, but how can I prevent the disappearance of the search bar (for exemple when we click on the "viewColumns" icon)?
Is there an easy way that I missed, or do I have to create a customized search bar (with `customSearchRender` ) and do something with the `hideSearch` function?

Comment: Also, I found that if I set `search: false` it prevent the searchbar to disappear when we click on other icons. But still, there is the searchbox cross that allows user to hide the search bar, and will have then no possibility to make it visible again.

Comment: Was this resolved?